# How to fix errors when deploying akaunting to kubernetes cluster?

Tags: php, laravel, kubernetes

I try to deploy the web-app [akaunting](https://akauntuing.com) to a k8s cluster.

Therefore, I converted the given (and working!) [docker-compose script](https://github.com/akaunting/docker) using [kompose](https://kompose.io) to k8s yaml files.

When I try to apply these files (given `AKAUNTING_SETUP=true`), I get the following error; I have no clue how to fix it...

```
Call to a member function get() on null
Setting locale en-US
Creating database tables
Connecting to database akaunting@akaunting-db:3306
Creating company
[2021-11-22 13:14:32] production.ERROR: Call to a member function get() on null {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function get() on null at /var/www/html/app/Abstracts/Commands/Module.php:59)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/overrides/akaunting/laravel-module/Commands/InstallCommand.php(50): App\\Abstracts\\Commands\\Module->createHistory('installed')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Akaunting\\Module\\Commands\\InstallCommand->handle()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(299): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(978): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(295): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Akaunting\\Module\\Commands\\InstallCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(167): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(94): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(186): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(263): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->call('module:install', Array, NULL)
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->call('module:install', Array)
#16 /var/www/html/database/seeds/Modules.php(32): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('call', Array)
#17 /var/www/html/database/seeds/Modules.php(20): Database\\Seeds\\Modules->create()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Database\\Seeds\\Modules->run()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php(149): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array, Array)
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php(49): Illuminate\\Database\\Seeder->__invoke(Array)
#25 /var/www/html/database/seeds/Company.php(20): Illuminate\\Database\\Seeder->call('Database\\\\Seeds\\\\...')
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Database\\Seeds\\Company->run()
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php(149): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array, Array)
#32 /var/www/html/app/Console/Commands/CompanySeed.php(36): Illuminate\\Database\\Seeder->__invoke()
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Console\\Commands\\CompanySeed->handle()
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#39 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(299): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(978): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#42 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(295): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(App\\Console\\Commands\\CompanySeed), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(167): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#44 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(94): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#45 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(186): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#46 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(263): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->call('company:seed', Array, NULL)
#47 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->call('company:seed', Array)
#48 /var/www/html/app/Jobs/Common/CreateCompany.php(50): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('call', Array)
#49 /var/www/html/app/Jobs/Common/CreateCompany.php(27): App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany->callSeeds()
#50 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php(29): App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany->App\\Jobs\\Common\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\MySqlConnection))
#51 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php(388): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->transaction(Object(Closure))
#52 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261): Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager->__call('transaction', Array)
#53 /var/www/html/app/Jobs/Common/CreateCompany.php(30): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('transaction', Array)
#54 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany->handle()
#55 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#56 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#57 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#58 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#59 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(128): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#60 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Bus\\{closure}(Object(App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany))
#61 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany))
#62 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(132): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#63 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany), false)
#64 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(405): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->dispatchSync(Object(App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany), NULL)
#65 /var/www/html/app/Utilities/Installer.php(241): dispatch_sync(Object(App\\Jobs\\Common\\CreateCompany))
#66 /var/www/html/app/Console/Commands/Install.php(82): App\\Utilities\\Installer::createCompany('Schokoladensouf...', 'finance@schokol...', 'en-US')
#67 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Console\\Commands\\Install->handle()
#68 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#69 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#70 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#71 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#72 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#73 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(299): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#74 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#75 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(978): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#76 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(295): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(App\\Console\\Commands\\Install), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#77 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(167): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#78 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(94): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#79 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#80 /var/www/html/artisan(22): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#81 {main}
"}
In Module.php line 59:
Call to a member function get() on null
```

If you need more information to answer, feel free to ask.
Any help is appreciated.

*Moved from [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/1084263/940982)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check if you're using [Bind Mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to create the volumes. If you are, then the files inside of the docker container are getting overwritten by those bind mounts.

To fix this, you can do something like run the container without the volumes (you could also change the entrypoint to simply bash if you wanted), copy the files out of the container onto the host, create the bind mount directory manually, copy the files into that directory, then start up the container with the bind mountpoints as volumes.

I've also raised this as a [github issue here](https://github.com/akaunting/docker/issues/53)

Answer (score 3):

### Workaround

Hi - I found the root cause of the problem - and answered the question yesterday night - but my post was deleted - not sure why (possibly since I hadn't finished registration???)

Turns out that the root of the problem is because the default Dockerfile image does NOT have the modules included. These modules seem to be downloaded after the first successful login (which interestingly requires the setup to finish - catch-22)!!!

Fix:

- Download the following 3 modules from their Github - offline-payments, paypal-standard and bc21.
- Extract the contents of these to 3 folders to the akaunting-modules volume - folder names need to be OfflinePayments, PaypalStandard and BC21 (guessing case sensitive).
- Restart the containers.

Let me know if that helps. I've got to the Wizard steps by doing the above.
After you pass the Wizard steps remember to restart with AKAUNTING_SETUP=false (checks for existing records don't seem to be great)
R. Saravanan

Comment: The missing files in the `modules` volumes were indeed the problem. As the docker image has the modules included, but they're hidden through the volume, I accepted the other answer, as it is slightly more precise. Thanks! @R. Saravanan & @smacz